# What happen if write() encounters disk bad sectors on Linux ext3

Tags: linux, filesystems

let’s say, my programm calls write() to write down some data to a disk partition formated with ext3. the disk just happen to generate a bad sector which the data will be flush to.

will write() return with errno? or the OS will move to another good sector and write() returns OK(also mark that bad sector for no longer used)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a file descriptor that you just open()ed, you'll have buffered access to the disk through the kernel vfs layer.  When you write() your write will be put in to a buffer in kernel and not actually written to disk.  So write() will succeed as normal.

If you want to *force* the changes to be written you'll have to [sync()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html).  If there was an error on disk, sync() will also succeed.  The place the error will show up is [dmesg](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dmesg.1.html).

NOTE that if it's a recoverable error it may be silently avoided and the bad blocks list updated for that disk.

Comment: let's assume the error is not recoverable, it is a hardware damage. you mentioned sync() will also succeed, so close() will succeed too, right? so, after the open-wirte-sync-close operations, there will a file exist in some directory. I wonder if the file is broken or is alright?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but my guess is the close wil also succeed.  if not you'll get EIO in errno.  it may alos depend on the features supported by the underlying storage (i.e. SAS or SATA).  Most (all modern?) disks do keep checksums and use ECC on the physical medium to detect errors, but that may not come up until the data is re-read.